# Same name contained in different street names - geocode.arcgis.com

Tags: arcgis

Hi everyone,

I've recently run into a problem when trying to geocode the position of a street whose name is contained into another street of the same city.

The street I was looking for is **Via Messina 20, Milano (9.1751, 45.4835)** , the other street is **Via Antonello da Messina 20, Milano** **(9.1423, 45.4659).**

In my web app I have a form with a text field that triggers **suggest** API call, using as input "Via Messina 20, Milano" returns as text "Via Messina 20, Milano" but the real result in terms of coordinates is the position of "Via Antonello da Messina 20, Milano" ([here](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=Via%20Messina%2020,%20Milano&f=pjson) you can have a look at the JSON response). I get the very same result from the Try Geocoding feature on arcgis website ([Geocoding and Place Search | ArcGIS for Developer](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/geocoding/) ). The "expected" result is not even shown in the list of available points.

The same problem happens with **find** API call, returns one result which is once again the wrong street ([here](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=Via%20Messina%2020,%20Milano&f=pjson) you can have a look at the JSON response).

To figure out why this was happening I tried a call to **findAddressCandidates** API and [here](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleLine=Via%20Messina%2020,%20Milano&category=&outFields=*&forStorage=false&f=pjson) the result is interesting: the "wrong" street is listed as first, while the "expected" one is in second place.

They both have Score 100% and they are both PointAddress.

So questions are:

- why the street name I type and send to **find** and **suggest** is not the first and expected result of my research?
- how can I achieve to show both of them at least in the **suggest** result list?
- why if I type "Via Messina 20, Milano" the **suggest** result shows as first entry "Via Messina 20, Milano" but referring to the wrong location ? (it is indeed "Via Antonello da Messina 20, Milano)
- is it a bug of the maps used by arcgis? (If I use google maps or open street maps it works fine)

Thanks,

LucioB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking directly with ESRI ArcGis support they told me that this issue is already known and still open.
This problem has impact only on arcgis-online servers and so doesn't affect your local services. It was introduced after v. 10.2.X

You can have more details [here](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA5NDM0Ng==) and [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-suggest.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F4600031F2F44E44ACE0989325BC9E0D)

Apparently at the moment the only way to handle correctly the results is to invoke the suggest service together with the findAddressCandidates and display the result of the merge between one response and the other.

They said bug is going to be fixed with 10.4 version.